# Get the Class of the called method in a method

Tags: java, class, methods, reflection

Okay, so my POV is that I have one single Method of the Application. The Main Method, from where everything is getting executed. Now I have to try and get all Classes that are connected with that Class.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    TestClass.executeSomething();
    Text.start();
    
}
```

And now I have to get, via reflection or something, the 2 Subclasses used in that class. In that Example: "TestClass" and "Text".

Is that somehow possible? I thank for every answer.

Comment: That is impossible. It sounds like you have some unstated problem, and you thought: Hey, if I can _just_ get all type names of everything I invoke in my main method, I solve my problem! But.. I don't know how to do that, so I better ask. This is an X/Y problem: You are asking questions about an imagined route to solve your real problem. But the route you imagined isn't a suitable way to go about it. Take a step back: What are you attempting to accomplish? There are plenty of ways to end up with modular / abstracted command systems in java. But this specific strategy isn't how to build them.

Comment: Okay, so its kind of very complicated but i'll try my best: Im changing files of API's, the API's only read the Files at the start of the API in a Map. To not have to restart and cancel processes of the running API I want to search for the Map in the entire API and then change the values in the map that were changed in the file. Another way would be getting the main class package and get every class that is in the same package or a subpackage. But I don't know if thats possible. I'm not really a pro in reflection

Comment: @rzwitserloot You should (already) know that bytecode inspection is one possibility ;-). But I agree on the XY-Problem. Mxrlin: Writing code that is [hot-swappable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping#Software) is *very* hard.

Comment: @Mxrlin an API is a formal definition (application programming interface). An API doesn’t do anything. Implementations do. Perhaps, you mean *classes*, but the way, you are using terms, forces us to guess about what you really mean. “files of API's”—do you mean class files? Does “changing” mean recompiling? And when you say “API's (plural) read files”, does that mean every class reads some files at startup?

Comment: @Holger Okay, yeah kind of bad written from me: Every, I called it API, but rather Sub-Application has a .json File where he saves data. Now the Main-Application, that changes the content of the .json File wants to change the data in the Application too, as the Applications don't get it everytime again from the .json but only get it at the start of the Application. Johannes Kuhn: Are there any API's to use "bytecode inspection"? Are there any good tutorials on how to use it?

Comment: Create a class that encapsulates the loading of the json file and the resulting map, then let each sub-application use an instance of it and only access the data through that object. That way, this object can perform a check, e.g. compare the file’s last modification date with the time of the last read, and read again when required. You could also incorporate the file notification API to find out about the change.